# Trying to return live/realtime output from shell command as string data from function to main function

Tags: qt, function, go

not sure how to explain this since I am using QT bindings in GO
so I pasted a mini version of the program.
I am trying to return from the run() func a live stream to the QT window..
I try this many ways... last one with channels(not succesfully)
what will be the best way to pass real time output to the main() function so my QT Slot can update the window?

package main

```
import (
        "fmt"
        //      "github.com/therecipe/qt/core"
        "bufio"
        "github.com/therecipe/qt/widgets"
        "os"
        "os/exec"
)

func run(input string) string {

        stream := make(chan string)

        fmt.Printf("You Clicked The Push Button %s\n", input)

        cmdName := "/usr/bin/nikto"
        cmdArgs := []string{"-host", input}

        cmd := exec.Command(cmdName, cmdArgs...)
        cmdReader, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Error creating StdoutPipe for Cmd", err)
                os.Exit(1)
        }

        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(cmdReader)
        go func() {
                for scanner.Scan() {
                        fmt.Printf("%s\n", scanner.Text())
                        stream <- scanner.Text()
                        //stream = fmt.Sprintf("%s\n", scanner.Text())
                }
        }()

        err = cmd.Start()
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Error starting Cmd", err)
                os.Exit(1)
        }

        err = cmd.Wait()
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Error waiting for Cmd", err)
                os.Exit(1)
        }

        input = <-stream
        return string(input)
        //return go getOutput(scanner)

}

func main() {
        // Create application
        app := widgets.NewQApplication(len(os.Args), os.Args)

        // Create main window
        window := widgets.NewQMainWindow(nil, 0)
        window.SetWindowTitle("nikto front end")
        window.SetMinimumSize2(400, 400)

        // Create layout

        Layout := widgets.NewQVBoxLayout()

        TopLayout := widgets.NewQHBoxLayout()
        //topright := widgets.NewQHBoxLauout()

        RLayout := widgets.NewQVBoxLayout()
        LLayout := widgets.NewQVBoxLayout()

        Layout.AddLayout(TopLayout, 0)
        Layout.AddLayout(RLayout, 1)
        Layout.AddLayout(LLayout, 0)

        //Create main widget
        mainWidget := widgets.NewQWidget(nil, 0)
        mainWidget.SetLayout(Layout)

        // Create left widget
        LQWidget := widgets.NewQWidget(nil, 0)
        LQWidget.SetLayout(LLayout)

        // Create right widget

        RQWidget := widgets.NewQWidget(nil, 0)
        RQWidget.SetLayout(RLayout)

        // Create label
        urlLabel := widgets.NewQLabel(nil, 0)
        urlLabel.SetText("Target: ")
        TopLayout.AddWidget(urlLabel, 0, 0)

        // Create a line edit
        input := widgets.NewQLineEdit(nil)
        input.SetPlaceholderText("Enter target like http://127.0.0.1")
        TopLayout.AddWidget(input, 0, 0)

        // Create checkboxes
        checkBox1 := widgets.NewQCheckBox2("Default", nil)
        //checkBox1.SetWindowTitle("Check Box")
        LLayout.AddWidget(checkBox1, 0, 0)

        checkBox2 := widgets.NewQCheckBox2("SSL mode", nil)
        //checkBox2.SetWindowTitle("Check Box")
        LLayout.AddWidget(checkBox2, 0, 0)

        checkBox3 := widgets.NewQCheckBox2("no 404", nil)
        //checkBox3.SetWindowTitle("Check Box")
        LLayout.AddWidget(checkBox3, 0, 0)

        output := widgets.NewQTextEdit(nil)
        LLayout.AddWidget(output, 0, 0)

        // Create a button and add it to the layout
        button1 := widgets.NewQPushButton2("2. click me", nil)
        Layout.AddWidget(button1, 0, 0)

        button1.ConnectClicked(func(checked bool) {
                output.Append(run(input.Text()))
        })

        // Set main widget as the central widget of the window
        window.SetCentralWidget(mainWidget)

        // Show the window
        window.Show()

        // Execute app
        app.Exec()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `run` return the channel, then read it in `main` (and don't read from the channel in `run`):

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    // ...

    button1.ConnectClicked(func(checked bool) {
            stream := run(input.Text())
            go func() {
                    for line := range stream {
                            output.Append(line)
                    }
            }()
    })

    // ...
}

func run(host string) <-chan string {

    var cmd *exec.Cmd
    cmdReader, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
            // ...
    }

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(cmdReader)
    stream := make(chan string)

    go func() {
            defer close(stream)

            for scanner.Scan() {
                    fmt.Printf("%s\n", scanner.Text())
                    stream <- scanner.Text()
            }
    }()

    go func() {
            if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
                    // ...
            }
    }()

    return stream
}
```

Comment: you the man! works like a charm.. I did had to comment your cmd pointer and add back my cmd,  cmd := exec.Command(cmdName, cmdArgs...) and the rest that you did not include and now it shows.. I love GO channels! this is helping me practice it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the call to `run` be asynchronous (which would require channels and goroutines)? If not you can simply use `bytes.Buffer` to capture command output and return (which is what our current implementation appears to be doing):

```
func run(input string) string {
    cmdName := "/usr/bin/nikto"
    cmdArgs := []string{"-host", input}

    cmd := exec.Command(cmdName, cmdArgs...)
    var b bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &b

    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return b.String()
}
```

Comment: hey! thanks so much. Not really I do not really mind how to do it.. as long it works.  I have test this and does not seem to work the way I want, basically the shell command has a constant stdout, as of now I will only get all the output at once when done.. what I need is for the output to show on the widget as it comes out  picure a tail -f /var/log/messages only that this is a command and does eventually finish running and of course is not a file.. :)  like this will be easy on shell with popen and similar system calls, issue here is with the function and the widget.

Comment: i think it would be better to use qt to render this feature as it is essentially a UI behavior. To get this behavior from `run`, you'll have to ensure `output.Append` can work with byte stream, which i don't think is the case.

Comment: hey thanks for your help, the other suggestion by Peter is exactly what I needed.. the issue is that the QT go libs I think are still missing the QProcess that is what runs system commands I opened a issue a couple days a go but had no response so just went the pure go route. https://github.com/therecipe/qt/issues/474